# Simple word problem about inequalities

Tags: inequality

Person $A$ can perform a task in $x$ seconds, while person $B$ takes $x+2$ seconds to do the same. When $A$ and $B$ collaborate, they manage to complete it in less than $t$ seconds. What is the maximum amount of time $B$ will take to complete the task if he is working alone?

I think solution may involve switching to frequencies, but haven't  quite gotten to a solution. Could anyone drop a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A can do the work in $x$ seconds, then the fraction of the total work A finishes within one second is $\frac{1}{x}$. Similarly, we obtain for B $\frac{1}{x+2}$.
Since you're interested in B's maximum time, let's for simplicity call $x+2 =: y$, hence $x = y-2$. Then the fraction of the work they finish working together within one second is $\frac{1}{y-2}+\frac{1}{y}$.

Both together work for less than $t$ seconds, so the fraction of the work both finish within one second has to be greater than $\frac{1}{t}$.

Based on that you can formulate an inequality which you can solve to find out what the maximum time to finish the whole work alone is for B.